# Why do I get told that everything is up to date when pushing to Heroku?

Tags: python, git, heroku

I have a small Pytorch/Flask model that I deployed to Heroku using Git (`git push heroku master`). Initially, my `static` folder had one file as an example, which got pushed to Heroku as well. Uploading files via one of the forms, however, is supposed to save files in that `static folder and then delete them once the user goes back to the home page. Obviously, the content of`static`changes over time so I expected getting a warning when doing`git push heroku master` about the changes I need to pull first. Surprisingly (or not), however, I get the message that everything is up to date.

Okay, that makes sense if we compare with the last thing I committed and pushed (nothing has changed), but isn't Heroku updating the files in that remote repo? If so, how can everything be up to date?

Comment: Writing a file to a local git checkout of a git repo does not also commit and push the change automatically. Your really should separate your data from your code.

Comment: You mean that any changes on Heroku's app are not tracked automatically and that's why I can't pull them?

Comment: @DonDraper, yes. Why would they be tracked automatically? Git doesn't track _anything_ automatically. (And you shouldn't be committing on Heroku, even if you do it manually. As Jordan said, code and data are different things. Code changes flow one direction, and data doesn't belong in Git at all.)